# replacing text in a printstream

Tags: java, regex, replace, printstream

Is it possible to have a regexp replace in a printstream?

I have a piece of code that logs all text that is shown in my console windows but it also logs ANSI escape codes.

I have found this regexp `"s:\x1B\[[0-9;]*[mK]::g"` to remove them but that only works with strings.
Is there a way to apply a regex replace to a constant stream of strings and filter out the ANSI escape codes?

If possible, dumb it down as much as possible, I am still a newbie when it comes to programming, I am just building upon a already program.

**EDIT:**

I have this code which I found somewhere else on stack overflow, this allows me to stream to a logfile and to the console at the same time.

This is what I use and then I set the out to tee after this.

```
Logging tee = new Logging(file, System.out);
```

.

```
package com.md_5.mc.chat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Logging extends PrintStream
{
  private final PrintStream second;

  public Logging(OutputStream main, PrintStream second)
  {
    super(main);
    this.second = second;
  }

  public void close()
  {
    super.close();
  }

  public void flush()
  {
    super.flush();
    this.second.flush();
  }

  public void write(byte[] buf, int off, int len)
  {
    super.write(buf, off, len);
    this.second.write(buf, off, len);
  }

  public void write(int b)
  {
    super.write(b);
    this.second.write(b);
  }

  public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException
  {
    super.write(b);
    this.second.write(b);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your question now solved then? If so, ideally you should repost that as an answer and mark it accepted. If not, can you explain how this affects your issue?

Comment: @DuncanJones This is my already existing code, I just don't know how I can edit the printstream (System.out) to filter the ANSI codes out of the outputstream to my file.

Comment: I assumed, other assumed, that you wanted a PrintStream which filters out the ANSI (as it is stated at the beginning). Then in the edit it talks about other code you are using (which happens to do an output duplication). So just to be sure: You want to get your code (which prints to two outputs) to also filter out a regex. Don't you? (maybe it should be stated more clear from the beginning)

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass the print stream in question and perform your regexp replacing prior to calling the appropriate `super` method? E.g.

```
public void ExampleStream extends PrintStream {

  @Override
  public void print(String s) {
    super(s.replaceAll(ANSI_PATTERN,""));
  }
}
```

Comment: There are many flavours for printing and writing. print(String) and other print() methods delegate on write(String). Would be better if you redefined write(String), but wouldn't be good enough if print(char[]) was used (for example).

Comment: Oops, Sorry I edited the answer, I was meaning to turn the literal into constant in my own edit. I'm not able to revert it.

Comment: @Javier No problem, it improved my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create create a subclass of `FilterOutputStream`, say `RegexOutputStream`. This class should buffer all data written to it (from the different `write(...)` methods). In the `flush()` method, it should apply the regex and then write the result to the underlying `OutputStream`.

Next, instantiate the `PrintWriter` to write to the `RegexOutputStream`. This way you don't need to alter the behaviour of the `PrintWriter` class. In case you don't want the filtering anymore, you can just take the RegexOutStream out of the chain, and everything will work again.

Note that, depending on how you use the `PrintWriter`, this might cause the `RegexOutputStream`s buffer to get quite big. If you create the `PrintWriter` to autoflush, it will flush after every line and after every byte array. See its [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) for details.

Comment: The idea (implement as a FilterOutputStream) is right, but the requester was asking for something more chewed down (newbie). I happened to have quite the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the code in `Logging` class is not a good approach (at least as it is):

- If you have access to the PrintStream source code you might find that the methods currently redefined might not being used at all: the PrintStream#print(...) methods delegate on textOut#write(...) (not on the redefined OutputStream#write(...) ).
- Therefore, you should redefine the print(String) and print(char[]) methods in order to effectively filter the output.
- There are a few examples of redefined methods in the answers (including further down on this one).

Alternatively, if you just want a PrintStream that filters out the ANSI codes (as I originally understood), then it would be more convenient to implement it on a FilterOutputStream (as mthmulders suggests, as you will have to redefine fewer stuff and will be easier to re-use):

- Make a copy of `BufferedOutputStream` class. Name it however you prefer. (E.g. **TrimAnsiBufferedStream**)
- Then redefine de flushBuffer() method:

  ```
  private void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
      if (count > 0) {
          String s = new String(buf, 0, count); // Uses system encoding.
          s.replaceAll(ANSI_PATTERN, "");
          out.write(s.getBytes());
          count = 0;
      }
  }
  ```
- When you need to instantiate a PrintStream that replaces ANSI, invoke `new PrintStream(new TrimAnsiBufferedStream(nestedStream))`.
- This is probably not bullet-proof (e.g. whatever may happen with encoding configuration, or if buffer size is not big enough, or flushing options in printstream), but I won't overcomplicate it.

By the way. Welcome kukelekuuk00. Just be sure to read the FAQ and feedback on the answers (we care about you, please reciprocate).

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how to do this, I am quite new to programming and I haven't done much java programming.


I made the copy of BufferedOutputStream (http://pastie.org/4366500) but I really don't know if I did it right and how to use this.

and Thank you and I will.

Comment: @kukelekuuk00 I don't know how to explain further. Though I might rob you the chance to wrestle with the problem, there you have the code for the class: (http://pastie.org/4366578). Hope that helps

Comment: I'll just look closely at what you did and continue from that.